# Exclude properties from serialization to Json string - DynamicJson

Tags: c#, json

I have an object which need to be serialized.
**Object to serialize:**

```
public class Setting
{
    // Exclude from serialization
    private SettingInfo _key;
    public SettingInfo Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set 
        { 
            _key = value;
            Key_Id = _key == null ? 0 : _key.Id;
        }
    }

    // Need to be serialized
    public int Key_Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to exclude the `SettingInfo` object (Property `Key`) from serialization using `DynamicJson`?

- I am using **`DynamicJson`**
- **Current result**: (which contains the serialized `Key` property)
  `{"Key":{"Id":20,"Type":"System.String","Name":"ExampleSetting"},

  "Key_Id":20,

  "Value":"New Value"}`
- **Requested result**: `{"Key_Id":20,"Value":"New Value"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would do it with property attribute, but in this lib there are no attributes.
Below is not very beautiful, but working solution.

```
var r = DynamicJson.Serialize(s);
DynamicJson tt = DynamicJson.Parse(r);
tt.Delete("Key");

r = tt.ToString();
```